# Highlight multiple edges in Cytoscape JS

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I have an undirected graph like this :

```
 var cy = cytoscape({
          container: document.getElementById('cy'),
          elements: [
            // nodes
            { data: { id: 'a' } },
            { data: { id: 'b' } },
            { data: { id: 'c' } },
            { data: { id: 'd' } },

            // edges
            {
              data: {
                id: 'ab',
                source: 'a',
                target: 'b'
              }
            },
            {
              data: {
                id: 'bc',
                source: 'b',
                target: 'c'
              }
            },
            {
              data: {
                id: 'cd',
                source: 'c',
                target: 'd'
              }
            }
          ],
          style: [
            {
              selector: 'node',
              style: {
                shape: 'hexagon',
                'background-color': 'red',
                label: 'data(id)'
              }
            }],
          layout: {
            name: 'grid'
          }
        });
```

As you can see you can go to `d` from `a` by using `c` and `d`. What I'm trying to achieve is if the edge `ab` is highlighted, the edges `bc` and `cd` will also be highlighted. Is there a way to do this? I couldn't find any source on this on the Internet... Thanks.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you mean.  You want to highlight all the edges in a component?  In a neighbourhood?  Something else?

Comment: @maxkfranz I want to highlight a path. I'm actually passing the path to the node.

Comment: @maxkfranz I mean if you can go from `a` to `d` and you know the path, I want to highlight all nodes and edges on that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the included algorithms like [Floyd-Warshall](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.floydWarshall) or [Dijkstra](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.dijkstra). From their output you should be able to generate highlighting for relevant edges.

Ex.

```
var dijkstra = cy.elements().dijkstra('#an_id')
var path = dijkstra.pathTo( cy.elements('node#another_id'))

path.forEach(function(ele){
  if (ele.isEdge()){
    ele.addClass("class_that_has_highlight_styling")
  }
})
```

Comment: I don't have problem with determining the path, I can't highlight the chosen path.

Comment: I added an example